# javascript append to array dynamically index

Tags: javascript

what i am trying to do is to create an array in which i will keep movie ratings from users who had rate the same movies that i have rate..i need those users in separate array depending on the length of my_ratings size. That means if my ratings was made from 3 movies i must have movie_users[1] = all user_ids who have rate also this movie 1...same for movie_users[2] and movie_users[3]..

```
    for(var i = 0; i < my_ratings.length; i++){
       for(var j=0; j < user_movie_rating.length; j++){
         if(my_ratings[i].movie_id == user_movie_rating[j].movieId){
           movie_users[i].push(user_movie_rating[j].userId);
          }
       }                             
   }
```

how can i do that?

Comment: you may illustrate your need with some data ... please have a look here: [mcve]

Comment: Please provide example data, and the result you would expect for those data.

Comment: are you sure about `movie_users[i].push`, the reference with `i`?

Comment: i want to have users depending on movie..so i need movie_users[0] = array(1,2,3,4...) thats the reason i use that reference i..

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash table and iterate only once for both arrays.

In the first loop over `user_movie_rating` set the hash table with the actual rating object and in the second loop over `my_ratings` check and push `userId` to `movie_users` with the actual index.

```
var hash = Object.create(null);

user_movie_rating.forEach(function (rating) {
    hash[rating.movieId] = rating;
});

my_ratings.forEach(function (rating, i) {
    if (hash[rating.movie_id]) {
        movie_users[i].push(hash[rating.movieId].userId);
    }
});
```

With ES6 you could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) instead of an object.